# Determine all characters present in a vector of strings

Tags: r, string, character

Say I have the following dataframe consisting of two vectors containing character strings:

```
df <- data.frame(
      "ID"= c("1a", "1b", "1c", "1d"), 
      "Codes" = c("BX.MX|GX.WX", "MX.RX|BX.YX", "MX.OX|GX.GX", "MX.OX|YX.OX"),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I'd like a simple way to determine which characters have been used in a given vector.  In other words, the output of such a function would reveal:

```
find.characters(df$Codes) # hypothetical function
[1] "B" "G" "M" "W" "X" "R" "Y" "O" "|" "."

find.characters(df$ID) # hypothetical function
[1] "1" "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

Comment: `unique(unlist(strsplit(df$Codes, '')))` and then `sort` it.

Comment: On which criterion is based the order of `find.characters(df$Codes)` output?

Comment: The order of the output doesn't matter.  I'm only interested in the content.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom function to do this.  The idea is to split the strings into individual characters (`strsplit(v1, '')`), output will be `list`. We can `unlist` it to make it a `vector`, then get the `unique` elements.  But, this is not sorted yet.  Based on the example showed, you may want to `sort` the letters and other characters differently.  So, we use `grep` to index the 'LETTER' character, and use this to separately `sort` the subset of vectors and concatenate `c(` it together.

```
 find.characters <- function(v1){
  x1 <- unique(unlist(strsplit(v1, '')))
  indx <- grepl('[A-Z]', x1)
  c(sort(x1[indx]), sort(x1[!indx]))
 }

 find.characters(df$Codes)
 #[1] "B" "G" "M" "O" "R" "W" "X" "Y" "|" "."

 find.characters(df$ID)
 #[1] "1" "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

NOTE:  Generally, I would use `grepl('[A-Za-z]', x1)`, but I didn't do that because the expected result for the 'ID' column is different.

Answer (score 1):

```
find.characters<-function(x){
  unique(c(strsplit(split="",x),recursive = T))
}
```